# $(\lambda I-A)\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ from $A\vec{x}=\lambda\vec{x}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm just starting to read about eigenvalues. My textbook says that $A\vec{x}=\lambda\vec{x},\enspace\vec{x}\ne\vec{0}$ (the definition of eigenvalue $\lambda$) is equivalent to asking that the homogeneous system $(\lambda I-A)\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ has a non-trivial solution. Is this a simple matter of some basic matrix algebra? For example, I can see:

$A\vec{x}=\lambda\vec{x}\Rightarrow A\vec{x}-\lambda\vec{x}=\vec{0}\Rightarrow (A-\lambda)\vec{x}=\vec{0}$

but not sure how to get from $(A-\lambda)\vec{x}$ to $(\lambda I-A)\vec{x}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you can't subtract a scalar $\lambda$ from a matrix $A$. It's simply not defined. So to be able to work with this equation in some meaningful way, notice that $\lambda x = I \lambda x$, which if you 'factor' out the $x$, you have an actual matrix that you can subtract from $A$. We have then that

$$A\vec{x} = \lambda \vec{x} \Rightarrow$$
$$A\vec{x} - \lambda \vec{x} = \vec{0} \Rightarrow$$
$$A\vec{x} - I \lambda \vec{x} = \vec{0} \Rightarrow$$
$$(A-I\lambda)\vec{x} = \vec{0}$$

Comment: Point taken, but how is it they switched the terms from $(A-\lambda I)$ to $\lambda I-A$?

Comment: Oh, never mind -- the equation equals zero, so they can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your work doesn't make sense as written; what does $A - \lambda$ mean?

Note instead that
$$
A\vec{x}=\lambda\vec{x}\implies\\
A\vec{x}-\lambda\vec{x}=0\implies\\
A\vec{x}-(\lambda I)\vec{x}=0\implies\\
(A - \lambda I)\vec{x}=0
$$

Comment: Point taken, but how is it they switched the terms from $(A-\lambda I)$ to $\lambda I-A$?

Comment: Oh, never mind -- the equation equals zero, so they can do that.